Can I get to know list of files/dir which rsync (or other program) transfers/deletes before actually making the sync?
I have two different linux machines(server websites) seperated by internet having similar directory tree and files. both can acess each other via ssh.
I want to sync certain directories, however I need to know before performing the actual sync about list of files and dirs that need to be transferred or deleted before I perform it.
Rysnc performs well to preform actual sync. But is there any option in it which shows me what changes will take place before performing it ?
Or is there any other linux program that can do that.
both linux machines can access each other via ssh
Thanks

For rsync you can use the option -n. This will run the process, print messages, but will do no changes. For more information you can check the man page.
